# TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} ' TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

Im trying to write a code that tracks the screen time usage. I came across this problem when trying to add something to a JSON file. I have no clue what it is as Im still relatively new to Python and all the other answers to similar questions on here have been so confusing that I dont understand and haven't yet found a definitive solution for my case

A lot comes before this, but this is the relevant code:

```
        elif load_json == False:
            # JSON wont load if empty and if that is the case then this line will activate
            data["activities"].append(self.process_json(data))
            added_to_existing = True

        if added_to_existing == False:
            # If this window is the first instance in Json file, it must create a new dict
            data["activities"].append(self.process_json(data))

        first_time = False
        with open("Screentime/activities.json", "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        return data

    def process_json(self, data):
        current_window_data = {
            "name": self.active_window,
            "time_entry": [TimeEntries.specific_times],
        }
        return current_window_data

class TimeEntries:
    def __init__(self, start_time_dt, end_time_dt):
        self.start_time_dt = start_time
        self.end_time_dt = end_time_dt
        self.start_time = self.start_time_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.end_time = self.end_time_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.days = 0
        self.hours = 0
        self.minutes = 0
        self.seconds = 0

    def specific_times(self):
        total_time = end_time - start_time
        print(total_time)
        self.days, self.seconds = total_time.days, total_time.seconds
        print(self.days)
        self.hours = self.days * 24 + self.seconds // 3600
        print(self.hours)
        self.minutes = (self.seconds % 3600) // 60
        print(self.minutes)
        self.seconds = self.seconds % 60
        print(self.seconds)

        return_list = {
            "start_time": self.start_time,
            "end_time": self.end_time,
            "days": self.days,
            "hours": self.hours,
            "minutes": self.minutes,
            "seconds": self.seconds,
        }
        return return_list
```

The error that this throws up is:

```
...
File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 431, in _iterencode
    yield from _iterencode_dict(o, _current_indent_level)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 325, in _iterencode_list
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 405, in _iterencode_dict
    yield from chunks
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 438, in _iterencode
    o = _default(o)
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.8_3.8.1776.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '

TypeError: Object of type function is not JSON serializable
```

If anybody could explain in simple english what is going on and how to fix this, please answer.

Comment: Is this the full traceback?  Also, what is ```self.active_window```?

Comment: `TimeEntries.specific_times` (in `process_json`) is wrong for two reasons. Firstly, `TimeEntries` is a class object, whereas you should be using an instance of it. Secondly, `specific_times` is a method, so you need to call it to get the return value. However, you haven't shown enough code to say exactly how this should be fixed.

Comment: Somewhere along the line you added a function object to the data you want to serialize. Likely that a place where you meant to call a function and add its result to the data but you missed the parens `()` and added the function. That's hard for us to spot. You can try to spot the problem by eye or maybe hack up some code that scans the data.

Answer (score -1):

I sort of fixed it by just added everything to the main class. I think that the switching between classes must have been the issue. Although I still dont really understand why the previous code didnt work and although this code is a lot dirtier and not so organized, it still works.

```
import win32gui
from time import time, sleep
import json
import datetime
from dateutil import parser
# from activities_to_large import *
# from main import *

previous_window = ""

first_time = True
start_time = datetime.datetime.now()
load_json = False


class ActivityList:
    def __init__(self, activities, active_window):
        self.activities = activities
        self.active_window = active_window

    def data_from_json(self):
        added_to_existing = False

        data = {"activities": []}
        if load_json == True:
            with open("Screentime/activities.json", "r") as f:
                data = json.load(f)
            for i in range(len(data["activities"])):
                if data["activities"][i]["name"] == self.active_window:
                    # append only time becausse this window already exists in JSON file
                    data["activities"][i]["time_entry"].append(
                        self.specific_times()
                    )
                    added_to_existing = True

        elif load_json == False:
            # JSON wont load if empty and if that is the case then this line will activate
            data["activities"].append(self.process_json(data))
            added_to_existing = True

        if added_to_existing == False:
            # If this window is the first instance in Json file, it must create a new dict
            data["activities"].append(self.process_json(data))

        first_time = False
        with open("Screentime/activities.json", "w") as json_file:
            json.dump(data, json_file, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        return data

    def process_json(self, data):
        current_window_data = {
            "name": self.active_window,
            "time_entry": [self.specific_times()],
        }
        return current_window_data

    def time_entries(self, start_time_dt, end_time_dt):
        self.start_time_dt = start_time
        self.end_time_dt = end_time_dt
        self.start_time = self.start_time_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.end_time = self.end_time_dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
        self.days = 0
        self.hours = 0
        self.minutes = 0
        self.seconds = 0

    # def current_time(self):
    #     # time = datetime.datetime.now()

    #     return_list = self.specific_times(start_time, end_time)
    #     return return_list

    def specific_times(self):
        total_time = self.end_time_dt - self.start_time_dt
        print(total_time)
        self.days, self.seconds = total_time.days, total_time.seconds
        print(self.days)
        self.hours = self.days * 24 + self.seconds // 3600
        print(self.hours)
        self.minutes = (self.seconds % 3600) // 60
        print(self.minutes)
        self.seconds = self.seconds % 60
        print(self.seconds)

        return_list = {
            "start_time": self.start_time,
            "end_time": self.end_time,
            "days": self.days,
            "hours": self.hours,
            "minutes": self.minutes,
            "seconds": self.seconds,
        }
        return return_list
```